# Java poi convert xml to xls

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have file in type xls with xml extension, I want to read it like excel file.
I trying

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

but it read only with xls extension.
someone know how??
thank

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the XSSF* Classes.

XSSF is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel 2007 OOXML (.xlsx) file format.

https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

Comment: It sounds to me as though the file that is being read is actually an Excel 2003 document that has been saved as XML. I doubt you'll be able to open that with Apache POI